# EF 6 query contains unmapped columns, breaking the query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EDMX (Entity Framework 6.1.3) that I'm using to query two different databases. There are some minor differences between the databases but I only want the common columns. I generated the EDMX from Database A, and removed the columns that were not in Database B from the Diagram and regenerated the code.

If I query database B the query contains the columns I removed, although the final SELECT does not. This means that the query fails.

The table mapping shows the columns, but with nothing on the Value/Property side:

[image: Removed properties from mapping]

The exception is:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException : An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid column name 'ValidFromDate'.
Invalid column name 'ValidToDate'.
Invalid column name 'LastPulled'.
Invalid column name 'IsCurrent'.
```

The query that is being sent to the server is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[c].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[c].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[c].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone], 
[c].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone], 
[c].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone], 
[c].[Email] AS [Email], 
[c].[Fax] AS [Fax]
FROM (SELECT 
[Person].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Person].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Person].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone], 
[Person].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone], 
[Person].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone], 
[Person].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Person].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
[Person].[ValidFromDate] AS [ValidFromDate], 
[Person].[ValidToDate] AS [ValidToDate], 
[Person].[LastPulled] AS [LastPulled], 
[Person].[IsCurrent] AS [IsCurrent]
FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Person]) AS [c]
```

As you can see there is an inner-query which contains the additional columns.

At this point I'm kind of stumped as to why this is happening. How do I remove these columns from both sides of the mapping, or otherwise stop EF from putting unwanted columns in ANY part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Borophyll for pointing me in roughly the right direction. Although their answer was not the solution to my issue, it did allow me to see the actual issue.

in the EDMX file there is also a entry that looks like this:

```
<EntitySet Name="Person" EntityType="Self.Person" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo">
    <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
    [Person].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Person].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Person].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone], 
    [Person].[WorkPhone] AS [WorkPhone], 
    [Person].[MobilePhone] AS [MobilePhone], 
    [Person].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Person].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
    [Person].[ValidFromDate] AS [ValidFromDate], 
    [Person].[ValidToDate] AS [ValidToDate], 
    [Person].[LastPulled] AS [LastPulled], 
    [Person].[IsCurrent] AS [IsCurrent]
    FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Person]</DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

And that's where the weird sub-query was coming. I think the reason is that the table has no primary key as it is part of a staging database.

I just deleted from the `SELECT` statement the last four columns and everything worked.

Comment: Interesting - I have seen these when I include a View in an EDMX, I don't remember having one on a table definition.  Great find - glad you were able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the EDMX designer and simply delete a column from an entity - this does not fully remove the column from the EDMX.  Assuming you truly want it gone, you can open the EDMX file with a text editor and remove it by hand.  To make sure that your manual changes trigger a rebuild of your auto-generated classes, edit it in Visual Studio and you shouldn't have an issue.

1. Right-click the EDMX in solution explorer
2. Open With...
3. XML (Text) Editor

I would expect if you were to open the EDMX, you would find something that looks like:

```
<EntityType Name="Person">
  <Property Name="FirstName" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="LastName" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="HomePhone" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="WorkPhone" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="MobilePhone" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="Email" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="Fax" Type="varchar" />
  <Property Name="ValidFromDate" Type="datetime" />
  <Property Name="ValidToDate" Type="datetime" />
  <Property Name="LastPulled" Type="datetime" />
  <Property Name="IsCurrent" Type="short" />
</EntityType>
```

And you would just remove the bottom 4 columns, save and close, and rebuild the project.

EDIT: In case anyone in the future references this answer, if you do not first delete the column in the designer (like the OP did in this case), there will be two other instances of the column(s) in the XML that you would also need to remove in order for it to compile.